# Flexagons and noncrossing partitions

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials, discrete-geometry

Turns out a couple of series related to the faces of flexagons

[image: Example Fexagon]

popped up in my explorations of combinatorial reciprocities in a group algebra for sets of partition polynomial (ParPs) related to the associahedra and noncrossing partitions of the Weyl-Coxeter groups $A_n$. Martin Gardner in his book [Hexaflexagons and Other Mathematical Diversions](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/focus/Gardner_Hexaflexagons12_1956.pdf) gives a brief intro to flexagons. (The image of the flexagon is from [Flexagon.net](https://flexagon.net/).)

One productive way, for me at least, to view the duality / reciprocity of the sets of ParPs is in their dual relation to compositional inversion and their ensuing characterization as pairs of generalized face- and h-polynomials.

At one level of duality, OEIS [A003169](https://oeis.org/A003169) and [A006013](https://oeis.org/A006013) are duals in the ParPs and both appear in Table 2.  Characterizations for some noncrossing families of digraphs and graphs of  “Generic Axiomatization of Families of Noncrossing Graphs in Dependency Parsing” by Anssi Yli-Jyra and Carlos Gomez-Rodrıguez.

At the same level of duality, or reciprocity, as the previous two series, [A002293](https://oeis.org/A002293) and [A006632](https://oeis.org/A006632) are duals. A002293 ($\frac{1}{3n+1} \binom{4n}{n}$) appears on p. 10 of “[The V-flex, Triangle Orientation, and Catalan Numbers in Hexaflexagons](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/college.math.j.43.1.006?read-now=1&seq=5#:%7E:text=https%3A//www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/college.math.j.43.1.006)” by Iacob, McLean, Wang, and its dual [A006632](https://oeis.org/A006632), or rather 2 * A00632 = [A112385](https://oeis.org/A112385), appears in "[Flexagons](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2310544?origin=crossref)" by Oakley and Wisner.

No doubt these are a generalization of the results in "[Flexagons Yield a Curious Catalan Number Identity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.5736.pdf)" by David Callan.

The dualities? At one rung of the ladders of duality: The Catalans of [A000108](https://oeis.org/A000108) are the constants of the the face (f-) polynomials of the associahedra (see [A126216](https://oeis.org/A126216) / [A033282](https://oeis.org/A033282) / [A086810](https://oeis.org/A086810)), i.e., they enumerate the vertices of the associahedra. They are the sum of the coefficients of the h-polynomials of the associahedra, the Narayana polynomials of [A001263](https://oeis.org/A001263) / [A090181](https://oeis.org/A090181). The refinement of the f-polynomials of the associahedra are the ParPs of normalized [A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437) / [A111785](https://oeis.org/A111785) and of the h-polynomials, the noncrossing partitions polynomials / refined Narayana ParPs of [A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264). (There are numerous, diverse combinatorial models associated to each set of ParPs--polygon dissections, convex polytopes, lattice paths and trees being popular.)

So, naturally **I'm interested in the literature that relates flexagons to noncrossing partitions (or associahedra), perhaps via their tree models. Any recommendations?**

Comment: I don't see any reason to prefer muscular, braggadocios polygons to regular ones.

Comment: Side question: Why was Feynman interested in flexagons? Did he see a connection to his physics?

Comment: @AlecRhea, ha, just pinch one.

Comment: Feynman was also interested in lock picking. Flexagons may just have been entertainment for him.

Comment: And painting nudes (of wives of Cal Tech students), playing the bongo drums, . . . .

Comment: Flexagons discussed also in "A Mathematical Tapestry" by Hilton, Pedersen, and Donmoyer.